# Only One Product and Product-view on frontsite

Tags: template, frontend, home, product-view

I would like to use Magento to sell only one Product with multiple product Attributes in my Store. So i want my ONLY product on the start site of the Magento Store with some Product Attribute Dropboxes. I ve seen that this is possible on sites like: [www.sita-shop.de](http://www.sita-shop.de)

you can see this is a magento theme customized and there is just 1 product and its on the start site of magento store.

would be very nice if anyone knows how to handle this and would help me.

thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento admin panel > System > Configuration > Under General > Web > Default Pages.

You'll find a Default Web URL which points to `cms` by default.

You can then use `catalog/product/view/id/123` (replace 123 with your product id) and the homepage will by default go to your single product page.